# sql - How Can I truncate Multiple Tables in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, truncate

```
$tblarray = array("abc1","abc2","abc3");    

$sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE table_type ='base table' and TABLE_CATALOG='mydb' order by TABLE_NAME";
$res = mssql_query($sql);
while($rowTable = mssql_fetch_array($res))
{
   if(in_array($rowTable['TABLE_NAME'],$tblarray))
   { 
    $sqlDel = "SELECT DISTINCT concat('TRUNCATE TABLE',TABLE_NAME,';')  
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'abc%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb'";
    $res_sqlDel = @mssql_query($sqlDel);
   }
}
```

First I get all the tables name from database then truncate specific tables. But this code not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Table_name from information_schema.tables  where table_schema='YOUR_DB_NAME';
```

Will return all the table names

1) Iterate over the result set.

2) Create another sql query like

```
 $query= "truncate table ".$resultSetRow['Table_name'];
```

Execute it in the loop. Basically it will iterate over result set and truncate all the tables one by one.

Comment: Actually i want to truncate some specific tables not all the table so can i do like this ?
$query= "truncate table ".$resultSetRow['Table_name']." WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'abc%'

Comment: @MuhammadHassan then update your query like this: 

select Table_name from information_schema.tables  where table_schema='YOUR_DB_NAME' and Table_name  like 'abc%'

Comment: Ok. Done. Thanks a lot @Danyal Sandeelo